# How to apply Principal Component Analysis for parquet file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, pca

I have aparquet file which contain id,feature .id is int and feature is double.I want to apply pca algorithm to reduce dimensions.

[image: parquet file]

```
 val lData =  sqlContext.read.parquet("/usr/local/spark/dataset/model/data/user")
val vecData = lData.rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.getInt(0),s.getDouble(1))).cache() 
val mat = new RowMatrix(vecData)
    val pc = mat.computePrincipalComponents(5)
    val projected = mat.multiply(pc)
val projectedRDD=projected.rows
 projectedRDD.saveAsTextFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/PCA")
```

but this error appear

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

how to solve it?

Comment: Hi @salma, can you share your schema for ``lData`` ? Seems like getting your double by position is not a good idea (``s.getDouble(1)``) .

Comment: Yes,I edit my data in question.

Comment: I tried your code with the provided data and it works (only had to reduce the number of top principal components to 2).Can you please share the result of  ``lData.printSchema`` in your case ?

Comment: I try but still same error.Are you try on parquet file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your error is at the second line of code you shared :s. Is your source file shareable so I can try to use it as you did ?

Comment: yes,error in second line .my file here https://www.mediafire.com/file/jlocidlwsoqhdfh/part-r-00000-7d55ba81-5761-4e36-b488-7e6214df2a68.snappy.parquet/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salma,

Using you file we can see that features is an Array[Double] :

```
lData.printSchema

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

For your code to work you can change your second line to :

```
val vecData = lData.rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.getInt(0),s.getAs[Seq[Double]](1):_*)).cache()
```

Note : Usually I only use features in Vectors. Depending on what your `id` represents, maybe you don't need the `s.getInt(0)` part.